# Request has incorrect content type when using Twilio and Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, twilio, twilio-api

I am following this Twilio tutorial on how to reply to SMS messages with my app:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-node-js

The tutorial assumes you're using Express, but I am doing this with a Cloud Function, so my code looks a bit different:

```
exports.sms = functions.https.onCall((req: any, res: any) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    if (req.body.Body === 'hello') {
        twiml.message('Hi!');
    } else if (req.body.Body === 'bye') {
        twiml.message('Goodbye');
    } else {
        twiml.message(
            'No Body param match, Twilio sends this in the request to your server.',
        );
    }

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

When I text my Twilio #, it hits that endpoint, but I get the following error:

> Request has incorrect Content-Type. application/x-www-form-urlencoded

How do I get around this?

Comment: Where is the error being issued from? (library/package)  What source statement is being executed?  What does the incoming message look like?  What does the definition of the Cloud Function look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up [callable type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and normal [HTTP type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  Please read the documentation to understand the difference.  Callable functions are intended to be invoked directly from your mobile app using the provided client SDK.  They provide two arguments: an input data object, and a context.  Callables do NOT provide "req" and "res".  If you want control over the the response, you should be using a normal HTTP function with "onRequest" instead of "onCall".

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to test your `onCall` function for example in Postman, you only need to add the required parameters based on specification -https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference
Required Header `Content-Type: application/json`
Required Body argument `data`